# How to run an Excel macro after a new mail is received in Outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to run an Excel macro when email with "subject" is sent to my inbox. I set up run a script in Manage Rules & Alerts in Outlook. When I receive a mail with "subject" nothing happens to the macro.

```
Sub Test(mail As MailItem)

    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Not ExApp Is Nothing Then
        ExApp.Run "'C:\Users\Desktop\Production v2.7.1.xlsm'!Main_function_Auto"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: On Error Resume Next bypasses errors and some think it means there are no errors. There must be an On Error GoTo 0 as soon as the reason for bypassing errors is over. Place it just after Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application"). If there are errors you can see them.

Answer (score 0):

When your calling Excel sub procedure from Outlook, make sure to include the module name -

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Workbook

    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Environ( _
                        "USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Production.xlsm")
    xlApp.Visible = True

'   // Run Macro in file
    xlBook.Application.Run "Module1.Main_function_Auto"

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: i did replace with this code. but the macro not runing also.

"USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Production.xlsm")

what did userprofile do here?  and am i need to give full file path to the excel location?

Comment: @NadalMir have you rename the module?

Comment: yes i did rename the module. the module name is ''mainFun". so i rename as it is.

Comment: @NadalMir okay make sure to update `"Module1.Main_function_Auto"` with `"mainFun.Main_function_Auto"` also make sure your Excel sub is `Public sub Main_function_Auto()` -

Comment: i did everything u instruct. same result. the excel macro not trigger. my excel already public sub